# In light of Stuxnet, why did Iran use Windows?

Tags: windows, virus, cyber-warfare

I don't understand why these companies/places that should have high security standards use Windows. The only reason would be that it is a system requirement for some software or hardware. But in these  cases they should demand it to also work on Linux.

Why do you think Iran used Windows? Do you think they still use it?

**EDIT:**
Just to make clear some points:

1. I had watched the amazing documentary "Zero Days" by Alex Gibney, so I know how the hack worked.

   Of course Linux is not bullet proof, but the security's purpose is not to make things impossible, but harder, and Linux (developed, tested and used by Google, Amazon, Oracle, IBM, ...) would make the challenge more difficult to NSA and Unit 8200.

   I **asked** because maybe it was a must to use Windows due to sw or hw requirements, and then maybe someone could comment on that.

Comment: They're now using a specially designed [North Korean OS](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/10/15/world/asia/north-korea-hacking-cyber-sony.html).

Comment: *"But in these cases they should demand it to also work on linux.*" - Linux is not the top secure system you might imagine. There were lots of successful privilege escalations attacks in the past and don't even start to talk about the security of X11. You might start reading about [linux myth security](https://www.google.com/search?q=myth+linux+security).

Comment: Linux is, in fact, less secure once a malicious package, designed for Linux, gets on the system and runs. There is less in the way of process isolation. Security by obscurity is not security.

Comment: don't compare consumer security needs and expectations to national security manners, they aren't the same at all.

Comment: @leandro if you are a govt, staring at your brand new nuclear reactor, you are not going to be asking yourself, "Hm, what OS should we use on this? What do you like? Windows? Mac OS? Qubes?" The manufacturer makes that decision for you.

Answer (score 3):

- They did have high security standards: their computers were air-gapped. "Bypassing an airgap" was a new thing that Stuxnet did.
- Stuxnet attacked certain PLC controllers; PLC control software is usually/often written for Windows (because that's what their customers expect).
- Stuxnet was custom software, targeted at Iran's reactors. Using something other than Windows wouldn't have saved them: Stuxnet would just have been written for whatever they used.
- The US DoD uses Windows, too....